Establish Audio Connection between raspberry pi 3 and 4G HAT with a TRRS cable
I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with an external USB soundcard plugged in. The RPi is connected to a 4G hat (Waveshare SIM7600 4G HAT). When I plug in a headset to the AV Jack of the hat, I can send and receive audio of a phonecall. Also, I can send and receive Audio through the USB-soundcard.
Now I want to connect them to each other, so that the audio from the phone call is send to the RPi and vice-versa.
So I tried by connecting them to each other with an TRRS cable. But unfortunately, this does not work, audio is neither send nor received.
The only thing I notice, is a short burst on the volume meter in pavucontrol when I do a phonecall and change the output of the hat by an AT-command. So I guess, they are connected somehow, but the problem is still, that no speech is transmitted.
Does anyone have experience with this and could help me?

please ask about the problem ... do not ask if someone is available to help ... this is a question and answer site ... simply ask a question that has a useful answer ... Does anyone have experience? has a useless yes answer
